# How to pass query string variable (like id, name, etc..) with url in safe way?

Tags: php

I just want to pass some query string variables with URL like below. But in this way anyone can see the passing variables. I can use `base64_encode()` and `base64_decode()` methods but these are also not secure. Because anyone can reverse it. Please help me if anyone have the best solution.

```
 header('Location: http://www.example.com?id='.$id);
 or 
 header('Location: http://www.example.com?name='.$name);
```

Comment: What you mean by safe way are you looking for encryption?

Comment: You should be taking care of these values in your inner code, not in the URL. It depends how safely you handle these values when received. i.e. sanitizing the received values before inserting into database and so on...

Comment: You can use some secure Hashing methods.

Comment: I just want to prevent to show actual values in URL. Like using encryption & decryption method but it can be reverse by the others.

Comment: Please see `mcrypt_encrypt()`

Comment: But it can be easily decrypt by using mcrypt_decrypt(). So anyone can see the passing variables.

Comment: [Check the first example. Decrypting is not as simple as `base64encode/decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php)

Comment: @AmitRajput `mcrypt_encrypt` uses key to encrypt and only you will know the key, no one else can decrypt it without knowing the key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the best and secure solution for this..

```
<?php
/*
 * PHP mcrypt - Basic encryption and decryption of a string
 */
$string = "Some text to be encrypted";
$secret_key = "This is my secret key";

// Create the initialization vector for added security.
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);

// Encrypt $string
$encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $secret_key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

// Decrypt $string
$decrypted_string = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $secret_key, $encrypted_string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

echo "Original string : " . $string . "<br />\n";
echo "Encrypted string : " . $encrypted_string . "<br />\n";
echo "Decrypted string : " . $decrypted_string . "<br />\n";
?>
```

Output will be like below:

```
Original string : Some text to be encrypted
Encrypted string : –LÁ`b]!üƒN{Iç&|«kÿÅLèëÉ°Xp
Decrypted string : Some text to be encrypted
```